# Cookie Domain not valid C#

Tags: c#, .net, cookies

I making a request of a third-party web service and writing my C# code (.net 4.0) based on a VB.net program (.net 3.5).  I'm pretty much copying the commands exactly, but no matter what I add as the domain to my cookie, it doesn't work and always gives me the error when i add the cookie to the container.

The 'Domain'='https://secure.uat.globallink.com/gtss/service/FileWebService' part of the cookie is invalid.

The VB.net program works fine with this code and in production.  I have no idea why this is happening.  The .add method is the same between 3.5 and 4.0 and I've tried this BugFix_CookieDomain code that is floating around on the internet with no help (I only have this one cookie).  I've also tried adding a URI field with no luck and changing the domain to "https://secure.uat.globallink.com" but nothing is working.  Please help, I feel like I'm going a bit bonkers here.  Thanks!

C#

```
 GTSSWebService.FxWebService wsDL = new GTSSWebService.FxWebService();

                wsDL.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(connectionCreds, Settings.mySettings.GTSSPassword);
                wsDL.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();


                wsDL.Url = "https://secure.uat.globallink.com/gtss/service/FxWebService";
                Cookie gtssConnCookie = new Cookie("SMCHALLENGE", "YES");
                gtssConnCookie.Domain = "https://secure.uat.globallink.com/gtss/service/FileWebService";
                wsDL.CookieContainer.Add(gtssConnCookie);
```

vb

```
Dim wsDL As New GTSSWebService.FxWebService

            wsDL.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(sCreds, Settings.DefaultSettings.PW)
            wsDL.CookieContainer = New System.Net.CookieContainer

            If Settings.DefaultSettings.ConnectLTS Then
                wsDL.Url = "http://" & Settings.DefaultSettings.LTSIP & "/gtss/service/FxWebService"
            Else
                wsDL.Url = Settings.DefaultSettings.GTSSURL.Replace("/FileWebService", "/FxWebService")
                Dim GTSSConnectionCookie As New Cookie("SMCHALLENGE", "YES")
                GTSSConnectionCookie.Domain = Settings.DefaultSettings.GTSSURL
                wsDL.CookieContainer.Add(GTSSConnectionCookie)
```

**NOTE - Settings.DefaultSettings.GTSSURL == "https://secure.uat.globallink.com/gtss/service/FileWebService"**

Answer (score 2):

C# wanted "secure.uat.globallink.com" for the domain without the https://  Dang